# iPhone drawing too much power from USB ports (yes, I believe it's the device). What can I do?

Tags: iphone, usb

The issue started a couple of days ago. My Macbook Pro kept restarting.
After some testing I've realized this happens only when my iPhone is plugged in for charging. 
I think it's the device fault because it happened on a friend MacBook too, even with different cables.

I've restarted the iPhone and nothing changed, any suggestion?